# Change text on login page in admin bro

Tags: node.js, reactjs, components, admin, admin-bro

The login page in admin-bro says 'Welcome!'. I need to change it to something else. is it possible in AdminBro??

PS: I'm using version AdminBro v1.6.6.
PPS: I've already tried [this](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/admin-bro/issues/347) and the corresponding links. It doesn't work for me. Is it because of the version I have?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside your adminbro index file:

```
const locale = {
  translations: {
    labels: {
      // change Heading for Login
      loginWelcome: '',
    },
    messages: {
      loginWelcome: '',
    },
  },
};

const adminBro = new AdminBro({
  // databases: [db],
  resources: allResources,
  rootPath: '/admin',
  locale,
  branding: {
    companyName: '',
    softwareBrothers: false,
    logo: '',
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you know hot to add the path for the logo correctly? I tried and it does not go through.

Comment: @lumayara place files in public folder and load static assets in node 
  app.use(express.static("public"));
like this 
then   branding: {
          companyName: "",
          softwareBrothers: false,
          logo: "/logo.svg",
          myTheme,
          favicon: "/favicon.png",
        },

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadAbdullah! I will try